# Ext.JS Store Record is undefined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, extjs

```
var debtProtectionId = 0
    // get the selected id of debt protection dropdown
    if (mainPanel.generalPanel.calculationsFieldSet.debtProtection.getValue() != '') {
        debtProtectionId = mainPanel.generalPanel.calculationsFieldSet.debtProtection.getValue();
    }
    // get the store record with this id
    var storeRecord = planCombinationsStore.getAt(debtProtectionId)
```

When I run the code it says 'storeRecord is undefined'.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Store.getAt` expects an index to its internal collection.  Do you mean [`Store.getById`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Store.html#method-Ext.data.Store-getById) instead?